# How to allow HTTP requests from forwarding rule only

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am setting up a HTTP load balancer for my compute engine instances. After the basic setup works, I want to block external HTTP access to my compute engine instances. All HTTP communication should go through the forwarding rule. How to configure the network firewall to achieve that?

So far my network firewall looks like:

> default-allow-http
>
> Allow from any source (0.0.0.0/0)
>
> tcp:80 ; tcp:443

I tried to change the source filter to 10.240.0.1/16 or my forwarding rule IP (107.178.254.89). None of these works.

Comment: I figured it out. As mentioned in [Health Check](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks#http_and_https_load_balancing), I put 130.211.0.0/22 as allowed source and nothing else. It works for me.